# Is a pinned photodiode necessary in a 4T APS cell?

Tags: cmos, image-sensor

I would like to know if a pinned photodiode (PD) is required or desirable for a 4T APS cell that performs global shutter?

If yes, Why is it so necessary instead of using a conventional PD?

[image: 4T APS Cell]